# Shall we pass injected object in another class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am just playing around the Dagger2 for DI implementation in Android.

My query is nothing about the problem that I am facing but just a knowledge gaining.

I intend to inject a class in my Activity and want to pass it to my ViewModel class. Is this a good approach to follow the best practices in Dependency Injection? Will it arise any issue related to leak or performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. You should use `scope` and make injection possible inside your `ViewModel`.

What you are trying to do is against the idea behind dependency injection. Dependency injection libs create a dependency tree based on your `Models` then allow you to use this tree in your application.

- If you are initializing each an every time, you do not know what is the current state of your object.
- Most of the time you need one instance in some scope like inside activities, or fragments ... this problem can be solved by `Dagger2` easily

Scope ensures you have only one instance inside the given scope.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but what if injected object requires activity Context. And also how it will be testable in Unit test.